# How to detect Screen Boundary using AndEngine gles1?

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, game-engine

I tried small game code using `AndEngine` gles1 in which i move sprite along screen.
I used `AnalogOnScreenControl` for moving my sprite along the screen. when i test it then sprite also move along the screen boundary means it goes top,left,right,down though the screen complete.Then i put top line as image and check collision between sprite and line but then sprite stick to that top line it doesn't move anywhere, so then i tried `onAccelerometerChanged()` method but it also doesn't work.

so, help me that how can i detect screen boundary so that sprite doesn't go beyond screen boundary. Is any tutorial on this then please give me link.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is anything like the Digital control then you should be overriding the method `onControlChange()`. In that method you would just need to set up something like

```
//As long as the sprite is in the bounds, then move the sprite
if(mSprite.getX() > 0 && mSprite.getX() + mSprite.getWidth() < CAMERA_WIDTH && 
      mSprite.getY() > 0 && mSprite.getY() + mSprite.getHeight() < CAMERA_HEIGHT){
     //Move the sprite here
 }
```

In essence, you want to use want to make sure that the sprite is within the bounds of the scene, which is determined by the camera you set.